# Linear grammar exercise

Tags: context-free-grammar

I am a student and i have an exercise with a  linear grammar G=(N, Σ,S,P) where N is a set of nonterminal symbols, Σ is a set of terminal symbols, P is a set of production rules, and S is the start symbol with the productions:

S->aS

S->bX

X->ε

1.So I have to describe N and Σ;

i think that N={S,X} and Σ={a,b} Σ without ε?

2.G is right-linear

3. Find 4 words for L(G): aab,ab,aaab,aaaab

4.I have to say the language : a*b?

5.I have to say a left -linear language for a*b.

I am blocked.Thank you a lot! :)

Comment: StackOverflow is not the place where others do your homework.

Answer (score 0):

Right about N and Σ. ε is not an alphabet symbol of the grammar but a symbol we use to denote the empty string. One could also write 
X ->
for the last rule.

Answers 2-4 are correct. Number 5 I do not understand.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! In fact i have to give a grammar G so the productions and G is left-linear and recognise a*b

Comment: S -> Xb, X -> Xa, X -> ε